# stdlib extension module _tkinter is missing

Tags: tkinter, module, python-3.12

I tried to install Python 3.12.2, but in the configure log, I found three problems:

- `--enable-wasm-dynamic-linking`
- `--enable-wasm-pthreads`
- Standard library extension module `_tkinter`

All three are missing. Here's what I did:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
sudo apt-get reinstall python3-tk
```

python3-tk is installed already
Do you have any ideas to solve these problems?

Comment: Does your system have a GUI or just a console? How did you install python?

Comment: If you build Python from source, you need to install the system development packages of `tk` and `tcl` in order to build `tkinter` module.

Comment: @TheLizzard my os Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

Comment: @acw1668 thank you for your help. I've installed tcl,and tkinter issue solved  but I'm still encountering issues with '--enable-wasm-dynamic-linking' and '--enable-wasm-pthreads' being missing. Could you please advise?

Comment: Pass the two flags when executing `configure`.